# How to amend SSRS/IIS garbage collection schedule

Tags: iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We've been having the problem described in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2eeab6cc-a0b9-4712-aae5-0f55ba1e643f/ssrs2k8r2-error-deviceinfo-name-already-exists-parameter-name-deviceinfoname

The recommendation from Microsoft is to increase the cleanup task to 48hrs for the internal .net IIS garbage collection process.

The OP suggested a more long term workaround, which we will be considering but in the interim, could anyone advise on how to go about doing Microsoft's suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you'll already know some of this, but am including it anyhow to try to be more complete.

In the thread you linked to, it sounds like the original poster might be confusing garbage collection (freeing up CLR memory that doesn't need to be allocated anymore) with application domain recycling (restarting the whole CLR application domain).

Recycling is controlled by the SSRS setting [`RecycleTime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx), which defaults to 12 hours, whereas garbage collection runs continuously as well as when the application is coded to call `GC.Collect()`.

The only SSRS setting related to GC that I know of is [`ProcessTimeoutGcExtension`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955811), which causes the process to crashdump and stop if it's unresponsive during GC for more than `ProcessTimeoutGcExtension` seconds. The Reporting Services service for SSRS 2008 R2 is set to restart automatically on failure by default, so it should bring itself up afterwards if it stops due to `ProcessTimeoutGcExtension`.

Both of these settings are in the Reporting Services configuration file, at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config` by default.

The error message in the thread seems unrelated to garbage collection or recycling, so I'm not sure that this actually helps with the original problem.

As an aside, as of SQL Server 2008, SSRS doesn't use IIS anymore, although it does use the same driver (http.sys) as IIS to manage connections.